# Firefox Extension: self.port.on not passing result to outer function

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**main.js**

```
var tURL;
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = self.data;

/*
contentScriptFile: [data.url("scripts/lib/jquery.js"),
                    data.url("scripts/lib/jquery-ui.js"),
                    data.url("scripts/platform.js")];
*/
// First time install
if (require('sdk/self').loadReason == 'install') {
  // Do something on the very first install
  tabs.open("http://www.example.com/test2.php");
}

require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", logURL);
function logURL(tab) {
  tURL = tab.url;
  console.log("LOGURL: "+tURL);

  var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("scripts/lib/jquery.js"),
                        data.url("scripts/platform.js"),
                        data.url("scripts/script.js")]
  });
  worker.port.emit("vsAPI", tURL);


  worker.port.on('getURL', function(callback) {
    var gotURL = data.url(callback);
    worker.port.emit("gotURL", gotURL);
  });

}
```

**platform.js**

```
function Platform() {
  var that = this;

  that.getURL = function (filename) {

    self.port.emit('getURL', filename);

    self.port.on("gotURL", function(callback) {
      console.log("gotURL: "+callback);
      var output = callback;
    });
    //console.log("output: "+output);
    return output;

  }
}
```

**Problem:**

platform.js emits to main.js

main.js receives, processes and passes back result to platform.js

platform.js receives result successfully.

However, I want to use the result outside of the port.on function...

I.E:

```
self.port.on("gotURL", function(callback) {
  console.log("gotURL: "+callback);
  var output = callback;
});
```

I want to use "var output" outside of self.port.on("gotURL")

Any ideas what I need to tweak please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a general Javascript question and not really specific to the add-on SDK. E.g. here is the same thing for [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307819/using-variable-outside-of-ajax-callback-function) or [Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442829/how-can-we-access-variable-from-callback-function-in-node-js).

You have basically two options:

1. Create a global variable and assign to it from the callback. E.g.

   ```
   // will be undefined at first, of course
   var output;
   self.port.on("gotURL", function(callback) {
     console.log("gotURL");
     output = callback;
   });
   setInterval(function() {
      console.log("output: " + output);
   }, 1000);
   ```

   The output will look something like this (i.e. `output` is undefined at first until the `gotURL` message comes through):

   ```
   "output: undefined"
   ...
   "output: undefined"
   "gotURL"
   "output: something"
   ...
   ```
2. Global variables always have a hackish feeling, so just stick to proper callbacks.

   ```
   self.port.on("gotURL", function(callback) {
     console.log("gotURL");
     myOtherAPI.doSomething(callback);
   });
   ```

Comment: Great answer.... so how would this work in my situation?

script.js is the main script that loads html on a webpage.... it requests the image URL... 

`code`platform.getURL("images/vsicon.png");`code`

...the request is passed to the middle script platform.js .... 

`code`function getURL() {
self.port.on("gotURL", function(callback) {
  console.log("gotURL");
  myOtherAPI.doSomething(callback);
});
}`code`

....platform makes the port.emit call to main.js... so in your example, how do I get the callback passed to getURL() in another function?