# Firebase Web - currentUser returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get my current user after the login, but this returning null.
There's my code:

```
var currentUser;
firebase
    .auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        currentUser = user;
        console.log(currentUser); //this returns my user object 
    });
console.log(currentUser); //this returns "undefined"

var otherCurrentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log(otherCurrentUser); // this returns "null"
```

Comment: look at this option may be it helps [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/firebase-auth-currentuser-shows-me-null-but-it-logged-in/68411/3)

Comment: I have tried, but doesn't work for me

Comment: solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684239/1356559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var otherCurrentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

This will return null because auth object has not been initialized, you need an observer to do that.
While Login, use observer and save the UID in localstorage, and while logout clear the localstorage

Observer

```
var currentUser;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
      currentUser = user.uid;
      console.log(currentUser); //this returns my user object 
      window.localStorage.setItem("UID",currentUser);
  } else {
      currentUser = "Error"
      console.log(currentUser); //this returns my user object 
      window.localStorage.setItem("UID",currentUser);
       alert(" Error in your login code");
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

After this, whenever you need to get the user id, just use

```
var getuid = window.localStorage.getItem("UID")
console.log(getuid) // will log the UID
```

While logout just remove it

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("UID");
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: does your browser support localStorage

Comment: It works for me: `localStorage.getItem('currentUid');`

Answer (score 2):

The `onAuthStateChanged` event fires whenever the user's authentication state changes. The `user` variable is only useful within that callback. You cannot transport it out of that function.

So all code that requires a user should be *inside* the callback:

```
var currentUser;
firebase
    .auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        currentUser = user;
        console.log(currentUser); //this returns my user object 
    });
```

For more on this, see some of these:

- [Using variable outside of ajax callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307819/using-variable-outside-of-ajax-callback-function)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)
- [Firebase Query inside function returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381006/firebase-query-inside-function-returns-null/28382922#28382922)

Comment: I want to use the currentUser or other function of firebase out of own function. I've tried the `firebase.auth().currentUser`, but it returns null. Did have one way to get the currentUser, after the login, out of this?