# firebase on auth state change only working if page loads after user is signed in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using onAuthStateChange to load data based on auth state.

When a user is logged in, newsitems are loaded.
When a user is logged out, newsitems are removed from the page.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {

   if(firebaseUser){
      // update Newsitems
      firebase.database().ref('news').once('value', function(snap){
         snap.forEach(snapChild => {
             addNewsItemToHTML(snapChild.val(), snapChild.key)
         })
      })
   }
   if(!firebaseUser){
      document.getElementById('newsitems').innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById('admin').innerHTML = '';
   }
});
```

This works if the user is logged in when the page loads. I can log out and log in and the newsitems disappear and appear appropriately.

But if the user is not logged in when the page loads, the newsitems will not appear if I log in. The news items only appear after refreshing the page.

I have researched this for hours and I can't find the answer. I think that because there is no user when the page loads, the reference is not created. Can anyone help?

Comment: After you log in, did you see the onAuthStateChanged being triggered?

Comment: Yes, I console.logged from inside the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

> You're not calling onAuthStateChanged. Instead you're telling Firebase
>   to call you when the authentication state changes, which may happen a
>   few times when the page is being re-loaded.
>
> When a page is getting loaded and there was previously a user signed
>   in, the auth state may change a few times, while the client is
>   figuring out if the user's authentication state it still valid. For
>   that reason, you may see a call with no user before seeing the final
>   call with the actual signed in user.

please go through [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50683852/5314179)

consider using `firebase.auth().currentUser` with a condition when you are loading your page. `firebase.auth().currentUser` which will give you the current logged in user unless user is signed out.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the listener from .once to .on and that worked.

Comment: glad to help you. :)