# Nuxt middleware not triggered upon initial render

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

The following code is meant to check the role of the user.
The middleware runs everytime the site is reloaded are a new route is taken.

```js
// Some nuxt middleware
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

export default function ({ app, store, route, redirect }) {
  app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // For some reason, this does not load every time.
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        console.log(userAuth)
        firebase
          .auth()
          .currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
          .then(function ({ claims }) {
          // some auth stuff
    })
  })
}
```

For some reason, if the site is reloaded this user auth function always returns `null`. This leads to that the rest of the functions fail due to the unknown user data / user roles.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {...})
```

So my question is, why does the upper function return `null` when the site is reloaded?

ps. Everything works normal if a new route is taken, it only fails when site is reloaded.

Comment: Hey, sadly I could not implement a proper solution yet I am still looking for something.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeEach` is a guard triggered when you navigate from a page to another page thanks to vue router, aka using `<nuxt-link>` or `$router.push`.

On the initial page load, there is no navigation because you're rendering the content generated by the server, not the client directly.

Definition of a middleware from [Nuxt's documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware)

> Middleware lets you define custom functions that can be run before rendering either a page or a group of pages (layout).

Notice, **before rendering**. This means that a middleware will be run as your `beforeEach` and on initial render.
Hence, you can totally strip the router guard part and simply let the middleware as this

```js
export default function ({ app, store, route, redirect }) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
  ...
```

Comment: I finally had the time to test and think about it. I already tried it some time ago but it is not my main problem. 
The big problem for me is that the:
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userAuth)=>{}) always returns "null" on page reload. Doesnt matter if it is inside the beforeEach guard or outside.

Comment: I just found that post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683852/sometimes-firebase-auth-onauthstatechanged-returns-user-of-null-when-i-refresh
I will try to find a Workaround based on this :)

Comment: Nuxt middleware-wise, it should work. Looks like `firebase` is using some listener for it to be triggered indeed. @MarcelKlein